# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\PHP\New\input.php on line 25

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

I'm facing an error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\wamp64\www\PHP\New\input.php on line 25"

Heres My Code, any help ll'be highly appreciated.

```
<HTML>
<?php

if($submit)
{
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
    mysql_select_db("learndb",$db);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO personnel (firstname, lastname, nick, email, salary)
    VALUES ('$first','$last','$nickname','$email','$salary')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "Thank you! Information entered.\n";
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
First name:<input type="Text" name="first">
Last name:<input type="Text" name="last">
Nick Name:<input type="Text" name="nickname">
E-mail:<input type="Text" name="email">
Salary:<input type="Text" name="salary">
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information"></form>
< ?
} 
?>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Formatting tip: Put 4 <space> characters first in each code row, and an empty row before the code block.

Comment: good lord, why are you having so many unnecessary spaces in all your code? `< ? p h p` and what are all those `<br>`

Comment: Near the end, you use a `<?` short open tag instead of the full `<?php` - could it be that your PHP installation is configured to not accept short open tags? It sounds like PHP is complaining because it sees a closing  `?>` tag when it does not expect one.

Comment: The `br` came from the initial question, as he didn't used a code block. The tags became visible because of an edit from another user. But yes, the spacing is strange. @Xatenev

Comment: this is for formatting purpose only here, @eisbehr

Comment: i'm using wamp @zenzelezz

Comment: `echo "Thank you! Information entered.\n";` I think you need to use double slash `echo "Thank you! Information entered.\\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Change `< ?` to `<?php`. Short open php tags are a bad practice and are not always enabled by default.
To enable short tags, go to your php.ini file and set `short_open_tag=On`. After that restart your Apache server.

Also for a short tag to work in your code you need to remove the space between < and ?.